# Laravel migration, column type YEAR

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I want a column to store years. Now I'm using

```
$table->unsignedInteger('year')->default('1900');
```

But, that allows numbers like `5` and `19`. I want to force four digits numbers, like `1992`.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in laravel documentation you can do this in your migration file

```
$table->year('year');
```

Comment: ok, I made it a `year` type, but the problem persists. It still recieves `5` or `19`

Comment: did you refreshed the migration ?

Comment: try setting a default to 2000 and check , i tried it after you said it didn't work but it did

Comment: I set 2000 as default, still the same. The column type `year` isn't wrong per se because a year `5` or `19` are valid years. I guess what I want is to set a minimun year of `1000` so it won't receive values lower that that

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$table->integer('year', 4);
```

remember use: If you want
Rollback & Migrate In Single Command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

or Drop All Tables & Migrate

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Comment: I tried that, gave me a multiple primary keys error when migrating :\

Comment: so, try with php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: I did, still same. I think I will make it a `year` type and validate the input in the code

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for you would be to save the field as a date. 
using Carbon.

And then set the date and month value to 01, and get the full year value,
this way you can then get the full year with $date->year